# Como passar trecho de nome de tabela ou view em tempo de execução no SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Necessito realizar uma consulta no SQL Server em que o nome da tabela ou view seja passada em tempo de execução.

Então, considerando que na base de dados existam várias tabelas com diferença apenas no final da tabela, exemplo: TB_CARGA_20230208 e TB_CARGA_20230209, como eu faria para consultar uma tabela passando o sufixo dela em tempo de execução?

Tentei da forma a seguir, mas sem êxito.

```
declare @tabela varchar(20);

set @tabela = '20230209';  

select *
from convert(varchar(20), dbo.TB_CARGA_) + @tabela;
```

É retornado o erro a seguir:

Mensagem 156, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 6
Sintaxe incorreta próxima à palavra-chave 'convert'.

Horário de conclusão: 2023-02-09T21:40:29.0510537-03:00

Comment: precisa jogar o comando todo numa variável e usar o `exec` para executar a query, assim por exemplo `@declare query varchar(max) set @query="select...." EXEC (@query)`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, deu certo aqui, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta executar assim

```
   DECLARE @TABELA VARCHAR(20),
        @SQLConsult NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQLConsult = CONCAT(N'','
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        dbo.TB_CARGA_',@TABELA
)

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  
     @stmt = @SQLConsult
    ,@params = N'@TABELA VARCHAR(20)'
    ,@TABELA = @TABELA
```